# Programmatically Check an Item in Checkboxlist where text is equal to what I want

Tags: c#, items, checklistbox

In C#, I am trying to Check an item in a CheckBoxList where the text equals what I require.

I would modify the code to check items that exist in the database.

**If you would like an example, I need to select the checklistbox item that equals to abc**.

Comment: Have you attempted this yourself yet?
Is the interface to the CheckBoxList something you dont understand?

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: Please see the FAQ regarding signatures in posts. I also removed your thank you line, because it's more likely than not that no one will help since you haven't shown that you've tried to help yourself.

Comment: I have spent the last two hours trying to get ways of working it but i can't seem to figure how to get the checkedListBox.SetItemChecked to relate it to an item in the checklistbox.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Assuming that the items in your CheckedListBox are strings:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
  {
    if ((string)checkedListBox1.Items[i] == value)
    {
      checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(i, true);
    }
  }
```

Or

```
  int index = checkedListBox1.Items.IndexOf(value);

  if (index >= 0)
  {
    checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(index, true);
  }
```

Comment: It's the value you want to match, E.G. a string literal of "MyValue"

Comment: `if(index > 0)` should be `if(index >= 0)`, since IndexOf can return zero if it finds the first item in the list. It returns -1 if the value isn't found.

Comment: Only the first item get checked how to use foreach using this method.

Comment: I don't see `.SetItemChecked()` as an extension

Answer (score 10):

Example based on ASP.NET CheckBoxList

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="checkBoxList1" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem>abc</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>def</asp:ListItem>
</asp:CheckBoxList>


private void SelectCheckBoxList(string valueToSelect)
{
    ListItem listItem = this.checkBoxList1.Items.FindByText(valueToSelect);

    if(listItem != null) listItem.Selected = true;
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SelectCheckBoxList("abc");
}
```

Comment: The FindByText function doesn't exist for me.

Comment: Is this an asp.net application? Let me know what version of .NET and what environment and I would be happy to provide you specific instructions.

Comment: Hi Jim, I will be using C#.Net in Visual Studio 2010, using Framework 4.0 Client.

Comment: Right, but what kind of project? Winform, Silverlight, ASP.NET...?

Answer (score 5):

All Credit to @Jim Scott -- just added one touch. (ASP.NET 4.5 & C#)

Refractoring this a little more... if you pass the CheckBoxList as an object to the method, you can reuse it for any CheckBoxList. Also you can use either the Text or the Value.

```
private void SelectCheckBoxList(string valueToSelect, CheckBoxList lst)
{
    ListItem listItem = lst.Items.FindByValue(valueToSelect);
    //ListItem listItem = lst.Items.FindByText(valueToSelect);
    if (listItem != null) listItem.Selected = true;
}

//How to call it -- in this case from a SQLDataReader and "chkRP" is my CheckBoxList`

SelectCheckBoxList(dr["kRPId"].ToString(), chkRP);`
```

Answer (score 0):

//Multiple selection:

```
          private void clbsec(CheckedListBox clb, string text)
          {
              for (int i = 0; i < clb.Items.Count; i++)
              {
                  if(text == clb.Items[i].ToString())
                  {
                      clb.SetItemChecked(i, true);
                  }
              }
          }
```

using ==>

```
clbsec(checkedListBox1,"michael");

or 

clbsec(checkedListBox1,textBox1.Text);

or

clbsec(checkedListBox1,dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value.toString());
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Answer (score 0):

I tried adding dynamically created ListItem and assigning the selected value.

```
foreach(var item in yourListFromDB)
{
 ListItem listItem = new ListItem();
 listItem.Text = item.name;
 listItem.Value = Convert.ToString(item.value);
 listItem.Selected=item.isSelected;                 
  checkedListBox1.Items.Add(listItem);
}
checkedListBox1.DataBind();
```

avoid using binding the DataSource as it will not bind the checked/unchecked from DB.