# Retrieve checked Items in checkedListBox from text file

Tags: c#, checkedlistbox

I have a text file with one word per line which represents the checkedListBox I have checked previously. Now when the application is re-run I want the checkedListBox items to already be checked, I've tried:

```
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"checked.txt");
foreach (var checked in file.ReadLine())
{              
        lstCheckBox.SetItemChecked(checked, true);
}
```

This doesn't seem to work, whilst debugging the application crashes, any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Error:

```
    InvalidArgument=Value of '97' is not valid for 'index'.
    Parameter name: index
```

**FIXED**

```
foreach (var checked in File.ReadAllLines(@"checked.txt"))
{
    int index = lstCheckBox.Items.IndexOf(checked);

    if (index > 0)
    {
        lstCheckBox.SetItemChecked(index, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the crash you get?

Comment: @Matthew Updated OP with the error

Comment: Does the checkboxlist contain at least 98 items?  Also, the first argument to `SetItemChecked` is an integer, I don't see you doing any conversion from string.  Is this the code in its entirety?

Comment: @Matthew The list contains 20 items, and this is the entire code for the retrieval yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `ReadLine` returns a single line, and you're iterating the characters in the line.

```
string line;
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    var index = int.Parse(line);
    lstCheckBox.SetItemChecked(checked, true);  
}
```

Should fix the problem.

Alternatively, you could use the following code instead (not using `StreamReader`).

```
foreach (var line in File.ReadAllLines("checked.txt"))
{
    var index = int.Parse(line);
    lstCheckBox.SetItemChecked(checked, true);      
}
```

Comment: >var index = int.Parse(line); returns error [Input string was not in a correct format.]

Comment: What does your file contain?

Comment: A word of what, how does it correspond to your list box?

Comment: The word is the checkedlistbox Item text

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9185770/programatically-check-an-item-in-checkboxlist-where-text-is-equal-to-what-i-want

Comment: Thanks File.ReadAllLines and the linked question got it fixed, cheers.