# How can I get value in values of item of checkboxlist ? c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, checkboxlist, reader

I want to match the values from reader and checkbox to change selected values of item of checkboxlist. But it does not work and I don't know what to do? Thanks.

```
   while (reader.Read())
        {
                       CheckBoxList1.Items.FindByValue(reader["malzeme_id"].ToString()).Selected = true;
         }
```

I tried also,

```
while (reader.Read())
        {

for (int i = 0; i < CheckBoxList1.Items.Count; i++)
            {

                if (CheckBoxList1.Items[i].Value.Equals(reader["malzeme_id"].ToString()))
                {

                    CheckBoxList1.Items[i].Selected = Convert.ToBoolean( reader["isSelected"]);

                }
```

}

Comment: Define "does not work". Does it not compile? Does it throw an exception? Does it produce the wrong result? Does nothing happen?

Comment: the code has error. it is turkish, I translate it as" object is not set by example of an object"

Comment: @lkalay I would imagine that is because FindByValue is returning null and then you are trying to set the Selected property on it - have you debugged? (i.e split in to 2 steps and see what FindByValue is returning)

Comment: How can i search or find of item values in checkboxlist to change selected value

Comment: @lkalay you are correct in the way you are doing it - it just appears that whatever reader["malzeme_id"] resolves to is not in the list. I would imagine it would be case sensitive - could that be the issue? Can you show what is in you list and what reader["malzeme_id"] is?

Comment: Did you debug to check if the reader has values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the first thing i found when I googled how to programaticly select a item in the list.

> Assuming that the items in your CheckedListBox are strings:
>
> ```
> for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
>
>  {
>   if ((string)checkedListBox1.Items[i] == value)
>    {
>     checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(i, true);
>    }
> }
> ```
>
> Or
>
> ```
> int index = checkedListBox1.Items.IndexOf(value);
>
> if (index >= 0)
> {
>   checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(index, true);
> }
> ```

This awnser was found on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9185770/programatically-check-an-item-in-checkboxlist-where-text-is-equal-to-what-i-want) post, and posted by `wdavo`.